# After laravel-mix upgrade app no longer sees global vars

Tags: vue.js, laravel-mix

I'm upgrading a project from laravel-mix v2.0 to v4.0 and I'm seeing an issue now where at runtime my components can't see globally scoped variables like they did before.  How can upgrading the build tool impact the runtime?

I see I can add [instance properties to the vue prototype](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Base-Example), but is that really the approach I need to take?  Seems like it should still be able to read global variables like it did before.

**html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var games = [
       // a bunch of objects
    ];
</script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
import ChannelSubscriptionSlider from './components/guild-subscriptions/ChannelSubscriptionSlider.vue';
Vue.component('channel-subscription-slider', ChannelSubscriptionSlider);
```

**ChannelSubscriptionSlider.vue**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
Vue.use(VueResource);
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            games: games, // undefined when used within this component, but used to work before upgrade
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 2**

Use `window.games, this would "register" your variables globally.

---

Although, what i do, is the following, consider a MPA not a SPA:

In app.js i just leave the following lines:

```js
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
```

In a separate file, called main.js that i made, i put this, as an example:

```js
import Sidebar from './components/layouts/Sidebar.vue'
import Topnav from './components/layouts/Topnav.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#sidebar',
  render: h => h(Sidebar)
});

new Vue({
  el: '#topnav',
  render: h => h(Topnav)
});
```

at the end of app.blade.php i put:

```html
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const user_props = {
        fullName : {!! json_encode(Auth::user()->fullName) !!},
        username : {!! json_encode(Auth::user()->username) !!},
    }

    user_props.install = function(){
      Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$userProps', {
        get () { return user_props }
      })
    }

    Vue.use(user_props);
</script>

<script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
```

This works because i mount vue in app.js but the components that use `user_props` are loaded after i declare and install the prototype... Also, since vue is mounted in app.js i can use `Vue.use(user_props);` after loading it...

And forgot to mention that in webpack.mix.js you should add the main.js:

```js
 mix.js('resources/js/app.js',          'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss',    'public/css')

    .js('resources/js/main.js',        'public/js/')
```

**Edit 1**

Based on your comments, and the docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#The-Importance-of-Scoping-Instance-Properties

The `$` is just a convention:

> ... We scope instance properties with $ to avoid this. You can even use your own convention if you’d like, such as $_appName or ΩappName, to prevent even conflicts with plugins or future features.

So with that in mind you could set it up as:

```
Vue.prototype.games = games;
```

then you can access it on every component as `this.games`

As the documentation implies, when doing this you've got to be careful to not overwrite it. So if you have it declared on the data section of your Vue components i think you should delete those lines...

Comment: So that's essentially what is defined in https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Base-Example - except why do the games.install as a function?

Comment: Well it really isn't different in this case the install is for making it "pluginlike" haha... forgot to mention you should use `Vue.use(games)` ... also i think you could set it up as ´Vue.prototype.games´, since the $ is just a convention: https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#The-Importance-of-Scoping-Instance-Properties then you could just, not define them in your data on your components since it should be available as this.games globally ...

Comment: So the challenge with that approach is I'm actually using `laravel-mix` on a laravel project.  Essentially what that means is I don't have a good way of injecting code between the imports and the instantiation of vuejs since all that's compiled into a single `app.js`.  Meaning I don't have a `Vue` object, it's all encapsulated into `app.js`

Comment: You can generate javascript with blade in your templates, it may not be optimal or a straightforward solution. But with this approach and Blade you can load stuff you don't want to load with ajax (axios, vue http, etc). Just be careful with plain text cause it may break the generated javascript.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, but mix generates a single J's file for my whole app, imports and all, so there's nowhere for me to assign this to the Vue prototype.  See https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/js/app.js for an example...

Comment: In app.blade.php after loading app.js, just don’t defer it, works for me... you can also remove the app mounting from the app.js file put it in other file and between the two files add a script with the vue prototype

Comment: Sorry dude, I made a fresh laravel install 2 days ago, i thought i was using the last version of laravel-mix (4), but no, I'm using 2... Great, now I'm curious of what would happen if I update hahaha...

Comment: No problem!  I appreciate the feedback.  I'll give the window route a go.